# Some of my divs won't fill the width of the screen. How do I fix this?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to clone the BBC website for educational purposes.

My newsbar and topicdiv divs refuse to fill the width of the screen. I would like some help understanding as to why and how I can remedy the problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Darren's BBC</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

    <style type="text/css">

        body {
            margin:0;
            background-color:violet;
            /* This ensures the topbar stretches all the way across the screen and fills the top */

        }

        #topbar {
            background-color:rgb(255,255,255);
            width:100%;
            height:40px;
            color:black;
            font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
            font-weight:bold;
            font-size:0.8em;
        }

        .fixedwidth {
            width:1000px;
            margin:0 auto;
        }

        #logodiv {
            padding-top:4px;
            padding-right:5px;
            padding-bottom:4px;
            float:left;
            border-right:1px solid #DDDDDD;
        }

        #signindiv {
            padding:8px 85px 11px 15px;
            float:left;
            border-right:1px solid #DDDDDD;

        }

        #signindiv img {
            position:relative;
            top:3px;
            padding-right:2px;
        }

        #menudiv ul {
            margin:0;
        }

        #menudiv li {
            padding:14px 17px 10px 17px;
            list-style:none;
            float:left;
            border-right:1px solid #DDDDDD;
        }

        #searchdiv {
            float:left;
            padding:8px 0 0 10px;
        }

        #searchdiv input {
            border:none;
            background-color:#E4E4E4;
            height:24px;
            width:190px;
            font-weight:bold;
            font-size:0.9em;
            padding:0 5px 0 5px;
            background-image:url("images/search.png");
            background-repeat:no-repeat;
            background-position:right center;
        }

        #newsbar {
            background-color:#BB1919;
            height:55px;
        }

        #newsbar p {
            margin:0;
            font-size:2.7em;
            color:white;
            font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
            padding-left:50px;
        }

        .break {
            clear:both;
        }

        #topicdiv {
            margin:0;
            background-color:#A91717;
            width:100%;
            height:37px;
        }

        #topicdiv ul {
            margin:0;
            padding:12px 0 5px 37px;
        }

        #topicdiv li {
            color:white;
            font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size:1em;
            list-style:none;
            float:left;
            border-right:1px solid #B73C3C;
            padding-left:11px;
            padding-right:11px;
        }

    </style>

</head>



<body>

    <div id="container">

        <div id="topbar">

            <div class="fixedwidth">

                    <div id="logodiv">

                        <img src="images/bbclogo.png" />

                    </div>

                    <div id="signindiv">

                        <img src="images/signin.png" /> Sign In

                    </div>

                    <div id="menudiv">

                        <ul>
                            <li>News</li>
                            <li>Sport</li>
                            <li>Weather</li>
                            <li>Shop</li>
                            <li>Earth</li>
                            <li>Travel</li>
                            <li>More...</li>
                        </ul>

                    </div>

                    <div id="searchdiv">

                        <input type="text" placeholder="Search" />

                    </div>

                    <div class="break"></div>

                    <div id="newsbar">

                        <p>NEWS</p>

                    </div>

                    <div class="break"></div>

                    <div id="topicdiv">

                        <ul>
                            <li>Home</li>
                            <li>Video</li>
                            <li>World</li>
                            <li>Asia</li>
                            <li>UK</li>
                            <li>Business</li>
                            <li>Tech</li>
                            <li>Science</li>
                            <li>Magazine</li>
                            <li>Entertainment & Arts</li>
                            <li>Health</li>
                            <li>World News TV</li>
                            <li style="border-right:none">More...</li>
                        </ul>

                    </div>

            </div>

        </div>      

    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of those divs are nested in a fixed width div that has a width of 1000px. Percentages are worked out using the space available to that object, so 100% for those divs would be 1000px rather than the full width of your screen.

Answer (score 0):

Just switch these 2 divs:

```
<div class="fixedwidth">
    <div id="topbar">
```

Switching them will make `#topbar` to inherit its parent width.

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/q9L01eob/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did:

```
.fixedwidth {
    //width:1000px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
#topicdiv {
    margin:0;
    background-color:#A91717;
    width:100%;
    //height:37px;
    position:absolute;
}
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ta4y2b0h/)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Darren's BBC</title>

<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

<style type="text/css">

    body {
        margin:0;
        background-color:violet;
        <!--This ensures the topbar stretches all the way across the screen and fills the top-->

    }

    #topbar {
        background-color:rgb(255,255,255);
        width:100%;
        height:40px;
        color:black;
        font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
        font-weight:bold;
        font-size:0.8em;
    }

    

    .fixedwidth {
        width:1000px;
        margin:0 auto;
    }

    #logodiv {
        padding-top:4px;
        padding-right:5px;
        padding-bottom:4px;
        float:left;
        border-right:1px solid #DDDDDD;
    }

    #signindiv {
        padding:8px 85px 11px 15px;
        float:left;
        border-right:1px solid #DDDDDD;

    }

    #signindiv img {
        position:relative;
        top:3px;
        padding-right:2px;
    }

    #menudiv ul {
        margin:0;
    }

    #menudiv li {
        padding:14px 17px 10px 17px;
        list-style:none;
        float:left;
        border-right:1px solid #DDDDDD;
    }

    #searchdiv {
        float:left;
        padding:8px 0 0 10px;
    }

    #searchdiv input {
        border:none;
        background-color:#E4E4E4;
        height:24px;
        width:190px;
        font-weight:bold;
        font-size:0.9em;
        padding:0 5px 0 5px;
        background-image:url("images/search.png");
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-position:right center;
    }

    #newsbar {
        background-color:#BB1919;
        height:55px;
    }

    #newsbar p {
        margin:0;
        font-size:2.7em;
        color:white;
        font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
        padding-left:50px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 1000px;
    }

    .break {
        clear:both;
    }

    #topicdiv {
        margin:0;
        background-color:#A91717;
        width:100%;
        height:37px;

    }

    #topicdiv ul {
        margin:0;
        padding:12px 0 5px 37px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 1000px;
    }

    #topicdiv li {
        color:white;
        font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size:1em;
        list-style:none;
        float:left;
        border-right:1px solid #B73C3C;
        padding-left:11px;
        padding-right:11px;
    }

</style>


<div id="container">

    <div id="topbar">
     

        <div class="fixedwidth">

                <div id="logodiv">

                    <img src="images/bbclogo.png" />

                </div>

                <div id="signindiv">

                    <img src="images/signin.png" /> Sign In

                </div>

                <div id="menudiv">

                    <ul>
                        <li>News</li>
                        <li>Sport</li>
                        <li>Weather</li>
                        <li>Shop</li>
                        <li>Earth</li>
                        <li>Travel</li>
                        <li>More...</li>
                    </ul>

                </div>

                <div id="searchdiv">

                    <input type="text" placeholder="Search" />

                </div>

               

        </div>
         <div class="break"></div>

                <div id="newsbar">

                    <p>NEWS</p>

                </div>

                <div class="break"></div>

                <div id="topicdiv">

                    <ul>
                        <li>Home</li>
                        <li>Video</li>
                        <li>World</li>
                        <li>Asia</li>
                        <li>UK</li>
                        <li>Business</li>
                        <li>Tech</li>
                        <li>Science</li>
                        <li>Magazine</li>
                        <li>Entertainment & Arts</li>
                        <li>Health</li>
                        <li>World News TV</li>
                        <li style="border-right:none">More...</li>
                    </ul>

                </div>

    </div>    
   

</div>

</body>
</html>
```